# How can I copy only odd numbered lines from one file to another?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a text file with some information. How can I write only odd numbered lines from that file to a new file?
Using shell script..

Comment: Look here https://superuser.com/questions/101756/show-only-odd-lines-with-cat e.g. `awk 'NR % 2 == 0' input.file > output.file`

Answer (score 12):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed '2~2d' file > new-file
```

This starts from the second line, matches every 2nd line after that, and deletes the matched lines from the stream. The remaining odd-numbered lines are redirected to a new file.

Comment: "*starts from the second line, matches every 2nd line after that*" Wouldn't that be all the **even** numbers?

Comment: @RonJohn yes, it matches the even numbered lines and deletes them from the stream, leaving the odd numbered lines intact. We could use `sed '1~2!d'` but why waste a byte?

Comment: @Zanna *but why waste a byte* - spoken like a true [code-golfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions)!  In fact you could save another byte with `sed 'n;d'`.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma for those of us who do not know `sed`: `n;d` prints the pattern space (the current line?) and replaces the pattern space with the next line, deletes it immediately, starts the next cycle: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-commands-list

Answer (score 9):

```
awk 'NR%2' file > newFile
```

NR is the number of the current line; `NR%2` = odd line

Comment: Is this because the rule is triggered when the result of `NR%2` equals 1?

Comment: @RonJohn, yes. `NR%2 = 1 = True` that triggers the default action : `print`

Comment: @JJoao: Minor nitpick: The Awk language has no real "true" value. Instead, every non-zero number evaluates as true in conditional statements.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, Thank you, I completely agree.  (my previous comment was oversimplifying the non-zero, non-empty-string )